# How to ADD and REMOVE in a new json-array element in PostgreSQL V9.4

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I`m making a loop to create a new json matrix with only certain elements, for this I need to go through the previously created json-array and PUSH (ADD ELEMENT) and POP (REMOVE ELEMENT) the elements according to the condition.

I receive something like that

```
[
{"id":1 , "data": "test_a"},
{"id":2 , "data": "test_t"},
{"id":3 , "data": "test_h"},
.....
]
```

and I`m doing something like this to the loop

```sql
DECLARE
_test       json;
i           json;
_new_jsn    json;
BEGIN
_test := SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('id', 1, 'data', 'test'))

        FOR i IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(_test) LOOP


            RAISE NOTICE 'element %',i;
        END LOOP;
```

From here, I don't know how to continue to make to ADD and REMOVE element in a new param.

My filter is based in an IF-ELSE so if I have

```
       FOR i IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(_test) LOOP
         IF i->>id > 2 THEN
         ..... Add the element in _new_jsn
         ELSE
         .... Remove/Ignore the element
         END IF; 
        END LOOP;
```

I want to receive after the loop something like this

```
[
{"id":3 , "data": "test_h"},
{"id":4 , "data": "test_c"},
.....
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "push" and "pop"? Do you really need to add/remove elements to the array at the end? Or do you just need to filter the elements in the array? By *what* condition or param do you need to make the choice between them?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, i dont know how to add element in a new variable wich is inside a Loop, for example if I have `_new_jsn =` `[{"id":1 , "data": "test_a"}]` and after the loop I want `_new_jsn= [{"id":1 , "data": "test_a"}, {"id":2 , "data": "test_b"}]`. 

About the filter is based in an IF - ELSE, but I already know how to do that, my principal problem is the equivalent to the push() "add" and pop()"remove" from JS

Comment: Are you looking to change the list in the JSON in the field?   If so, you need to reassemble the JSON and write it as one thing.

Comment: Where do the values of the second element come from (`2`, `test_b`)? Does the condition depend on the first element in the array?

Comment: Stop thinking precedural and in terms of JSON. Write a declarative SQL query that constructs the data that you want in the end.

Comment: @GrantJohnson I need to create a new JSON-ARRAY based in the filter, with `json_array_elements(_test)` I already separated each element in a particular JSON, so the only that I need to do is check the conditional to know if that JSON i need to add or ignore in the new element `_new_jsn`, but i dont know how to add or remove in this case.

Comment: @Bergi I already edit the question and put what do i hope to receive after the loop

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for

```
DECLARE
  test CONSTANT json := json_build_array(
   json_build_object('id', 1, 'data', 'test_a'),
   json_build_object('id', 2, 'data', 'test_t'),
   json_build_object('id', 3, 'data', 'test_h'),
   json_build_object('id', 4, 'data', 'test_c')
  );
  result json;
BEGIN
  result := (SELECT json_agg(el)
    FROM json_array_elements(test) AS t(el)
    WHERE (el->>'id')::int > 2);
  -- …
END;
```

You don't need any loop or `IF` statements here. Just a `SELECT` query with a `WHERE` clause.

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=caee201aeee38fc7fdc084a86f2083a4) (I haven't found a better way to print the result than to raise an exception :-/)